# group by Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, grouping, ransack

I have a `Products` and `ProductSize`, that connected by `product_id`.
This my controller and model below.

```
def index
 @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
 @products = @q.result.group(:product_sizes)
end
def product_query_params
 params.permit(q: [:weight_lteq, :weight_gteq, :price_lteq, :price_gteq])
end
---------------
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_sizes
  has_one :image
end
```

```
Product.last.product_sizes is ProductSize id: 1163, name: "75 х 190 х 21 ", price: 24700, created_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:34", updated_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:34", product_id: 18

Product.last.product_sizes.last is ProductSize id: 1242, name: "180 х 220 х 21 ", price: 59280, created_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:35", updated_at: "2020-04-04 11:44:35", product_id: 18

Product.last is Product id: 18, name: "Доктор A2 S1200", about: " ", weight: 100, guarantee: 24, height: 21, spring: nil, orthopedic: true, custom_size: true
```

How to combine search fields that are in different entities (objects) in Ransack?
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome here @WWW1981, what is the question?

Comment: Hi @WWW1981 welcome to stackoverflow, can you add proper question to the title, since this will make it easier for someone to spot it and maybe answer you question.

Comment: how to make both fields work together, not separately? @Dylan

Comment: how to make both fields work together, not separately?  - @useme-alehosaini